# I'm having some difficulties understanding §5.1.1.2/2 in N1570

Tags: c, newline

§5.1.1.2/2 in N1570:

> Each instance of a backslash character (`\`) immediately followed by a
>   new-line character is deleted, splicing physical source lines to form
>   logical source lines. Only the last backslash on any physical source
>   line shall be eligible for being part of such a splice. A source file
>   that is not empty shall end in a new-line character, which shall not
>   be immediately preceded by a backslash character before any such
>   splicing takes place.

Reading this paragraph my understanding is that **only** the backlash character(`\`) is deleted, when it is immediately followed by a new-line character. But after reading other posts here in SO, about this paragraph, I came to the impression that both the backlash character and the next new-line character are eliminated from the source character set making up the file. Which one is correct?

Comment: "Each instance of a **backslash character (`\`) immediately followed by a new-line** character is deleted ..." - read the bold part as the "instance".

Comment: I have to say that this was the best answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both backslash and newline are deleted.

```
a \
b
```

is read as `a b`.

Answer (score 1):

the english is ambiguous in the first phrase, but the intent is made clear by the second phrase: The backslash and the new line are deleted